# How do I add "On Update Cascade" to my existing MySQL tables through PHPmyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cascade

So I'm doing some work on this database with many tables, several of which have a 1 to many relationship to several other tables. I recently realized I'd made a mistake in one of my PARENT keys, and I updated it thinking it would update in the foreign key. I was very confused when it didn't. I then learned that I would have had to set up a "On Update Cascade" on the table (With the foreign key?) if I wanted automatic updates to take place. However, I'm pretty far along with my database development and I'd like very much not to have to start my tables over just to add this feature into my tables.

I'm using PhpMyAdmin to do pretty much everything, and I can't seem to find a button that will do this for me. So What I need to know is: Is there a way I can retrofit my foreign keys so that future updates cascade as needed?

The Following 3 tables are examples of tables in my database. (This code was taken from the EXPORT files)

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `Icon_Stats` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Stat` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Meaning` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `Icon_Values` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `Icons_Apt` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Species` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'All',
  `Trait` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Stat` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Value` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Color` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Img` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

**Icons_Apt** has 4 foreign keys, but for the sake of this example I've only listed 2: **Stat** from **Icon_Stats** and **Value** from **Icon_Values**. I've combed the export file for Icons_Apt, but I can't find anything stating that either of those fields have a foreign key. I'm not sure how my database would know about all the relations if I were to export and then re-import all this data.

In any case, **is there a way for me to update the current tables to "On Update Cascade"?** Or would I have to delete the tables, create a new one and import all the data again?

Comment: Save your schema.  Drop the database.  Edit the saved schema.  Reload the schema.  Alternatively, edit the saved schema to give it a new name and load that.  If all seems well, then drop the old database.

Comment: @Wallyk - This sounds like a pretty good way to go about this, and I might just do that, but I still need to figure out HOW to add the "On Update Cascade" to my tables. Can you help me with that?

Comment: All I would do is look at the [command syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html).  But I don't see anything about cascading.   But [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) is something maybe helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your tables relations with phpmyadmin.

- go to the table you want to update
- click on "structure" tab
- then click "Relation view"

see the screenshot for more details :

[image: Update table realtions]

[image]

Comment: I'm able to access my "Relation View" fine, it's how I set up my foreign keys in the first place. However there doesn't seem to be a button that would allow me to add "On Update Cascade" to my foreign keys from here. And I have the most recent version  (I think) of PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: you must choose your table and column in order to get relations options, checkout my answer ive added another screenshot.

Comment: Whoa, wait, I don't have that screen. How can that be when I have the latest version of PhpMyAdmin? Am I supposed to set something up under configurations or something?

Comment: I am using WAMP 2.5 with PHPMyAdmin : 4.1.14, I didn't change anything on configuration, this is a default option, what are you using ?

Comment: I'm using MAMP 3.2.1 and PHPMyAdmin 4.4.1.1, These sound like newer versions, so theoretically I should definitely have that screen you're looking at?

Comment: Here is an img of what I'm looking at: http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn12/ladyesori1/Relation_view_zpsbhv5peug.png